How to match the size of an HStack to its parent view in certain context?
I am trying to recreate Whatsapp's message reply functionality in SwiftUI.
Basically I have a view that represents a message and the max width of the message is 300. So when a message has an older message linked to it (the message that was replied to), it will be placed on top of the message just like whatsapp.
The problem is, is that I want the older message to extend to the same size of the message. (Check the images I attached to see what's going wrong)
When the older message is the same size / longer than the reply
when the older message is shorter than the reply
As you can see in the 2nd image, i need the dark blue background to extend all the way.
BUT, I don't want to make the width infinity because I don't want it extending all the way unless the reply does. If that makes sense. I just want the older message background to match the reply without making the reply have a lot of empty space to the right.
Here is my code:
struct DMMessageBubbleReceiver: View{
    
    let impactMed = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .medium)
    
    @State var message: Message
    
    @State private var showActionSheet = false
    
    @State var userUID: String
    
    @State var showEmojis = false
    
    @State private var scale: CGFloat = 0.5
    
    @State var emojis = ["", "❤️", "", "", "✈️", "☠️"]
    
    @Binding var blurEverything: String
    
    @ObservedObject var homeData = HomeViewModel.shared
    
    @State private var offsetX: CGFloat = 0
    @Binding var isReplying: Bool
    @Binding var replyToMessage: MsgReply
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
            
            if showEmojis {
                
                HStack(spacing: 17) {
                    
                    ForEach(emojis, id: \.self) { emoji in
                        Button(action: {
                            impactMed.impactOccurred()
                            withAnimation {
                                showEmojis.toggle()
                                blurEverything = ""
                            }
                            homeData.addRemoveEmoji(message: message, emoji: emoji, userUID: userUID)
                        }) {
                            Text(emoji)
                                .font(.custom("Poppins-Regular", fixedSize: 18))
                        }
                    }
                }
                .padding(.horizontal).padding(.vertical, 5)
                .background(Color(UIColor.systemGray5).cornerRadius(50))
                .padding(.bottom, 5)
                .scaleEffect(scale)
                .onAppear {
                    withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.3)) {
                        scale = 1.2
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.3) {
                            impactMed.impactOccurred()
                            withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.3)) {
                                scale = 1.0
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
            HStack {
                
                HStack {
                    
                    if message.deleted != true {
                        
                        ZStack(alignment: .bottomTrailing) {
                            
                            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0){
                                
                                if let reply = message.reply{
                                    
                                    HStack{
                                        
                                        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5){
                                            
                                            Text("You")
                                                .font(.custom("Gilroy-Medium", fixedSize: 12))
                                                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                                                .lineSpacing(5)
                                            
                                            Text(reply.msg)
                                                .font(.custom("Gilroy-Medium", fixedSize: 13))
                                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                                                .lineSpacing(5)
                                                .lineLimit(3)
                                            
                                        }
                                        
                                    }.padding(10).background(Color.blue.opacity(0.07).cornerRadius(5)).padding(.horizontal, 5).padding(.top, 5)
                                    
                                }
                                
                                Text(filterLinksInText(message.text))
                                    .font(.custom("Gilroy-Medium", fixedSize: 15))
                                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                                    .lineSpacing(5)
                                    .padding(.vertical, 14).padding(.leading, 10).padding(.trailing, 15)
                                    
                                
                            }
                            .background(Color(UIColor.systemGray5).opacity(0.6))
                            .cornerRadius(12, corners: [.topLeft, .topRight, .bottomRight])
                            .offset(x: offsetX)
                            .gesture(
                                DragGesture()
                                    .onChanged { value in
                                        if message.deleted == false {
                                            if value.translation.width > 0 {
                                                offsetX = value.translation.width
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    .onEnded { value in
                                        if offsetX > 100 {
                                            
                                            impactMed.impactOccurred()
                                            
                                            withAnimation {
                                                isReplying = true
                                                replyToMessage = MsgReply(id: message.id, msg: message.text, name: "name")
                                                offsetX = 0
                                            }
                                        } else {
                                            withAnimation {
                                                offsetX = 0
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                            )
                            
                            if message.emoji != "" {
                                Text(message.emoji)
                                    .font(.system(size: 12))
                                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                                    .padding(3)
                                    .background(Color("messagebackground"))
                                    .cornerRadius(50)
                                    .offset(y: 8)
                                    .offset(x: 8)
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        Text("This message was deleted")
                            .font(Font.system(size: 13))
                            .italic()
                            .fontWeight(.medium)
                            .foregroundColor(.black.opacity(0.6))
                            .padding(.horizontal)
                            .padding(.vertical, 10)
                            .background(Color(UIColor.systemGray5))
                            .cornerRadius(12, corners: [.topLeft, .topRight, .bottomRight])
                    }
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: 300, alignment: .leading)

                Spacer()
                
                ZStack(alignment: .bottomTrailing) {
                    Text(" ")
                }.padding(.trailing)
                
            }
            
            Text("\(message.timestamp.formatted(.dateTime.hour().minute()))")
                .font(.custom("Gilroy-Medium", fixedSize: 11))
                .foregroundColor(.black.opacity(0.3))
                .padding(.leading, 5).padding(.top, 8).padding(.bottom, 10)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
        .padding(.leading)
        .padding(.horizontal, 10)
        .blur(radius: (blurEverything != "" && blurEverything != message.id) ? 2 : 0)
        .onTapGesture(count: 2) {
            if message.deleted != true{
                self.likeMessage(message: message)
            }
        }
        .onTapGesture(count: 1) {
            if message.deleted == false {
                withAnimation {
                    showEmojis.toggle()
                    if blurEverything != "" {
                        blurEverything = ""
                    } else {
                        blurEverything = message.id
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .onLongPressGesture {
            showActionSheet = true
        }
        .actionSheet(isPresented: $showActionSheet) {
            ActionSheet(title: Text("Message Options"), buttons: getButtons(message: message))
        }
    }
    
    func getButtons(message: Message) -> [ActionSheet.Button] {
        var buttons: [ActionSheet.Button] = []
        
        if message.deleted != true {
            buttons.append(.default(Text("Copy"), action: {
                self.copyText(message: message.text)
            }))
        }
        
        if message.deleted != true {
            if message.numLikes > 0 {
                buttons.append(.default(Text("Unlike"), action: { self.likeMessage(message: message) }))
            } else {
                buttons.append(.default(Text("Like"), action: { self.likeMessage(message: message) }))
            }
        }

        if message.deleted == false {
            buttons.append(.destructive(Text("Delete"), action: {
                self.deleteMessage()
            }))
        }

        buttons.append(.cancel(Text("Cancel")))

        return buttons
    }

    func copyText(message: String) {
        UIPasteboard.general.string = message
    }

    func likeMessage(message: Message) {
        impactMed.impactOccurred()
        homeData.likeDMMessage(message: message, userUID: userUID)
    }
    
    func deleteMessage() {
        impactMed.impactOccurred()
        homeData.deleteDMMessage(userUID: userUID, message: message)
    }
    
    func filterLinksInText(_ text: String) -> String {
        do {
            let regexPattern = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "https?://([-\\w\\.]+)+(:\\d+)?(/([\\w/_\\.]*(\\?\\S+)?)?)?", options: .caseInsensitive)
            let modifiedText = regexPattern.stringByReplacingMatches(
                in: text,
                options: [],
                range: NSRange(location: 0, length: text.utf16.count),
                withTemplate: "****"
            )
            return modifiedText
        } catch {
            return text
        }
    }
}


That is way more code than you need for a [mcve]. You should isolate the problem and produce the minimal code needed to reproduce it. From the images it looks like you just need a Spacer() wrapped with a if.

Your reply view did not have a width constraint to fill its parent. So you need either, add a Spacer or set frame(maxWidth: .infinity) to it. It cannot be overwhelmed since its parent had .frame(maxWidth: 300).
VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
    if let reply = message.reply {
        HStack {
            ...
            
            Spacer() //<- here
        }
        //.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading) //<- or here
    }
}

Output:

